# How to mock $window.innerWidth AngularJS with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

In my AngularJS (1.4.4) app I have factory:

```
    ( function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("app")
        .factory("DeviceTypeService", DeviceTypeService);

    function DeviceTypeService($window) {

        function isTablet () {
            var width = $window.innerWidth;
            return width > 639;
        }

        return {
            isTablet: isTablet
        };
    }

})();
```

I need to perform a unit test for it with Jasmin, running on Karma. I tried different solutions, but my test fails every time.

One of my solutions:

```
'use strict';

describe('DeviceType Service', function(){
 var mock_window,
     sut;

 beforeEach(function(){
   module('app');
   mock_window = {innerWidth: 1000};

   module(function($provide){
        $provide.value('$window', mock_window);
    });
 });

 beforeEach(inject(function(_DeviceTypeService_){
   sut = _DeviceTypeService_;
 }));

 it('isTablet() method shoul return "true" if $window.innerWidth > 639 px', function(){
    expect(sut.isTablet()).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

This test return `FAILED Expected false to be truthy`. I almost tried to create SPY for `$window.innerWidth` but it doesn't work too.

I use:
PhantomeJS (v 1.9.18).
Jasmine (v 2.3.4).
Karma (v 0.13.10)

Please show me my mistake or give some reference to a working code.

Comment: How can you create a spy for `$window.innerWidth`. It is an object not a function. Jasmine spies only work on functions.

Answer (score 1):

I have not managed to find out what's wrong, because when I tried your example, it's completely OK and the test passes.

I've put your sample on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ny8x/372/) - you can check it yourself: "run" & all are green in the output.

The only things I added were:

```
link to http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/lib/jasmine.js
link to http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/lib/jasmine-html.js
link to http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/lib/jasmine.css
link to http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/lib/boot.js
link to http://code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/angular.js
link to http://code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/angular-mocks.js

var myApp = angular.module('app', []); - before your code

uninteresting copy of IsTablet - just to play with and see something red

copied-pasted a simple Jasmine runner at the end of the file
```

So.. it's safe to say that's no actual changes.

Try it yourself on the fiddle and if there's no important changes with respect to your code, check if the libs versions are the same, check if you didn't forget something like angular-mocks

FYI: at first, I didn't notice the versions you used and I tested your code at angular 1.2.9 and jasmine 1.3 - it worked. When I updated fiddle to use angular 1.4.4  and jasmine 1.3 - it still worked. Now I updated it to almost your version - 1.4.4/2.3.0 - still works. I didn't found any 2.3.4 mirrors.

..so, maybe it's something with Phantom? but that'd be quite strange since it shouldn't do anythign special to angular's $window.